# Browser style tabs in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I have emacs 27.2 and when I open a buffer, I want to have browser style tabs.

I do M-x tab-bar-mode, and it says "tab bar mode enabled."

But then there is no tabs at the top of the buffer. And I try to do C-x t 2 to add a new tab, and nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong? I tried following youtube videos and I feel frustrated, because I am typing the exact same things and getting different results.

Edit: I just tried tab-line-mode and now I see a tab-line. Is that more what I'm supposed to use instead of tab-bar?

Comment: Are you using Emacs in terminal mode, e.g. `emacs -nw`? Maybe that doesn't support showing tabs. If not, provide a recipe to repro what you see, starting with `emacs -Q`. Say what you do, step by step, what you see at each step, and what you expected to see instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you were on macos then emacs will not show the tab-bar on gui. It's not fully supported yet.